# Nodemon server restarts but does not run changes; how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

PS E:\GIT_Project\phone-shop\Backend> npm run server

> backend@1.0.0 server
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...

"scripts": {
"start": "node server",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
},

how to fix it?